# Does AWS SSL only need to be configured on a load balancer for both my instances?

Tags: security-certificate, amazon-aws

I have two instances of production configured in AWS which are load balanced. I want to update the domain validated certificate for both the instances.Just wanted to confirm is the following place the only place where I would need to update the certificate?

[image]

So if I upload a new domain validated certificate from the third party CA, will that get used for both the instance? Also, is there any other place where I would need to make any changes?

Answer (score 1):

AWS loadbalancers have the ability to handle all the encryption.   That means that you put the certificate only on the load balancer. Client web browsers connect to the load balancer via HTTPS.     The load balancer then connects to your instances via HTTP.

In that configuration the load balancer is the only place that needs the certificate.  The individual instances do not need a copy of it.   It is how I have my site on AWS configured, and it works fine.

Comment: In case I am uploading domain validated certificate for one domain, how is it going to work since my prod and qa domain names are different.

Comment: I have a SNI certificate that covers all of my host names.   One certificate can work with multiple domains.